# External point of an ellipse

Tags: geometry

Let $P$ be a point on an ellipse with foci $F_1$ and $F_2$. Let $Q$ be an external point. Is it true that $QF_1+QF_2>PF_1+PF_2$ ?

I think there's something that escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true. The ellipse is the locus of points $P$ for which $PF_1 + PF_2 = k$, where $k$ is some constant. The ellipse divides the plane into two regions where $PF_1 + PF_2 < k$ (inside) and $PF_1 + PF_2 > k$ (outside).

More info [on this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse). Pay special attention to the "pins and string" method of drawing an ellipse -- to move your pen outside the ellipse, you'd need to lengthen the string (i.e. increase the value of $PF_1 + PF_2$).